# How to build libclang_rt.builtins.a?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to build Chromium, and I get an error that the file `libclang_rt.builtins.a` is missing. It seems that this file is  a static library that is part of compiler-rt, so it should be getting built when I build LLVM. Unfortunately, this file indeed cannot be found anywhere in the build tree. Here's how I built LLVM and libc++:

```
cd llvm-project
mkdir ../llvm-and-libcxx-build
cmake -G Ninja -S llvm -B ../llvm-and-libcxx-build -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=all -DLLVM_RUNTIME_TARGETS=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cd ..
ninja -C llvm-and-libcxx-build runtimes
```

The build was successful; it just didn't build `libclang_rt.builtins.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nigelp-xmos provided the answer on Discourse](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/libclang-rt-builtins-a-is-not-being-built/72862/2): it turns out that `-DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=all` does not actually enable **all** runtimes, but only libcxx, libcxxabi, and libunwind. It is necessary to specify any other runtimes, including compiler-rt, explicitly if one desires to build them. Switching to `-DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;compiler-rt"` and redoing the build resulted in `libclang_rt.builtins.a` being built successfully.